# Can't get output after selecting sel=5'b101 from mux

Tags: multiplexer

```
module ram_mux(yout,data_in,enable,sel,clk);
input [3:0] data_in;
output [3:0] yout;
input enable,clk;
reg enable0,enable1,enable2,enable3,enable4,enable5,enable6,enable7;
input [2:0] sel;
wire [3:0] register [7:0];
reg [3:0] mux_input [7:0];
wire [3:0] temp0,temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5,temp6,temp7;
data_register  a6 (register[5],data_in,enable,clk);
buffer         a14 (temp5,register[5],enable5);
mux            a17 (yout,temp0,temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5,temp6,temp7,sel);
always@(clk)
begin

$monitor($time,"register[5]=%b,temp5=%b,enable=%b,enable5=%b,yout=%b,sel=%b",register[5],temp5,enable,enable5,sel);
#30 enable5=1;
endmodule
module data_register(yout,data_in,enable,clk);
input clk,enable;
input [3:0] data_in;
output [3:0] yout;
reg [3:0] yout;
always @(clk)
begin 
    if(enable==1)
    begin 
    yout=data_in;
//  $monitor($time,"yout=%b,data_in=%b,enable=%b",yout,data_in,enable);
    end

    else 
    yout=4'b0000;
end
endmodule
module buffer(y_output,x_input,enable);
input [3:0] x_input;
output [3:0] y_output;
reg [3:0] y_output;
input enable;
initial 
begin 
assign y_output = enable? x_input : 4'b0000;
//$monitor($time,"y_output=%b,x_input=%b,enable=%b",y_output,x_input,enable);
end
endmodule
module mux(yout,temp0,temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5,temp6,temp7,sel);
input [3:0] temp0,temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5,temp6,temp7;
input [2:0] sel;
output [3:0] yout;
reg [3:0] yout;
initial 
begin 
case (sel)
     3'b000:yout=temp0;
      3'b001:yout=temp1;
      3'b010:yout=temp2;
      3'b011:yout=temp3;
      3'b100:yout=temp4;
      3'b101:yout=temp5;
      3'b110:yout=temp6;
      3'b111:yout=temp7;
      default:yout=4'b0000;
endcase
//$monitor($time,"yout=%b,sel=%b,temp5=%b,temp4=%b",yout,sel,temp5,temp4);
end
endmodule
```

As `enable=1`, `register[5]==data_in` will be executed. As `enable5==1`, `temp5==register[5] ////temp5 loaded with temp5`.

But when I select `sel=4'b101` in the multiplexer in the testbench I can't get `yout`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Your mux block should be using `always @(*)` rather than `initial`.

Comment: sorry sir for trouble but thank for help this post help me lot.thanks a lot such a silly mistake i had done but some time you know our mistake we can identify that  coding